# Pivot table & Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm using this query to get previous 12 months Sales.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
    gp_etablissement [ETABLISSEMENT],
    datename(month, dateadd(m,-1,getdate())) [Month], 
    COUNT(1) [Sales Count]
    FROM PIECE
    GROUP BY gp_etablissement,
    datename(month, dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))) AS MontlySalesData
PIVOT( SUM([Sales Count])   
    FOR Month IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December])) AS MNamePivot
```

I got this error :

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
>   an outer reference.

I've changed many columns in the group by, but same problem.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  Why are you grouping by the current month and then expecting to unpivot the value.  You are going to get only one column with a value, depending on the current month.

Comment: I want to get value of last previous 12 months, and i want to rename each column (Month) with his name. Ex : [Month - 1] must : April.

Comment: This is why sample data and desired results are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for eliminating the error. The pivot doesn't work with the subquery that way when the group by uses date parts.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    gp_etablissement [ETABLISSEMENT],
    datename(month, dateadd(m,-1,getdate())) [Month], 
    COUNT(1) [Sales Count]
    FROM PIECE
    GROUP BY gp_etablissement,
    datename(month, dateadd(m,-1,getdate())) 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
PIVOT( SUM([Sales Count])   
    FOR Month IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December])) AS MNamePivot
```